# Adding a text box to an excel chart using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to add a text box to a chart I've generated with openpyxl, but can't find documentation or examples showing how to do so. Does openpyxl support it?

Comment: will you be able to add a screen shot of the chart with the text that you speak of (generated using excel itself) so that we have a better idea of what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

I also haven't been able to figure out how to do this via OpenPyXL, but you can add a textbox using [XLSXWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_textboxes.html).

Note that you can use both OpenPyXL and XLSXWriter at the same time, but it is important to complete the changes you are making in OpenPyXL and save/close the workbook before re-opening it in XLSXWriter and adding the textbox. *(Otherwise, stating the obvious, you could save over any changes (e.g. the textbox) made by the second package.)*

FWIW, on my laptop at least, the test workbook opens waaaaaay faster in XLSXWriter than it does in OpenPyXL. A workbook with 10 single-page worksheets, crammed with formulas, formatting, data - takes 8 secs to load in OpenPyXL and about .003 secs to load in XLSXWriter. So re-opening the workbook a second time is not that big a deal, even if processing dozens of workbooks.

Here is a simple code example for creating a textbox using XLSXWriter:

```
import xlsxwriter as xlwr
xlwrwb = xlwr.Workbook('c:\myworkbook.xlsx')
xlwrsheet = xlwrwb.get_worksheet_by_name(sheet.title)

rrow = 10
ccol = 8
ttxt = "This is an example textbox created by OpenPyXL." 
xlwropts = {
    'width': 400,
    'height':200,
    'fill': {'color': '#EEE8AA'},
    'align': {'vertical': 'middle', 'horizontal': 'center'},
    'font': {'bold': True, 'name': 'Arial', 'size': 16, 'color':'orange'},
}
xlwrsheet.insert_textbox(rrow,ccol,ttxt, xlwropts)
xlwrwb.close()
```

### UPDATE:

Have been working on this example since posting above code and I stand corrected. The XLSXWriter docs certainly demonstrate adding a textbox as per above code, but XLSXWriter cannot make changes to an existing Excel workbook. It only can create new workbooks - and it cannot use an existing Excel workbook as a template, even.

I will attempt to find [another package](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/alternatives.html) that can do this, but at this point it doesn't look good.

Here's hoping the good minds at OpenPyXL (Charlie?) can provide a near-enough solution using the [DrawingML specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774351/1447509), but at this point that is beyond my own abilities.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html

Comment: Hi, do you know if there's been any update on this? I am also trying to make a text box

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "text box". In theory you can add pretty much anything covered by the DrawingML specification to a chart but the practice may be slightly different.

However, there is definitely no built-in API for this so you'd have to start by creating a sample file and working backwards from it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply; regarding the "text box", I mean the same that as, in excel,when you insert -> shapes -> textbox onto a chart. I'm converting a VB marco to python (using openpyxl) and am trying to figure out how to replicate the VB code .Shapes.AddTextbox(...)

Comment: It might be possible but you'll need to do some reverse engineering to see what's needed. I've implemented some but by no means all the DrawingML objects: it's a real rabbit hole!