# How to add textbox to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to add a textbox to an excel file using openpyxl. There seems to be some support, as there are modules openpyxl.drawing.text, but I find no example / documentation, how to use them.

There is on open question: [Adding a text box to an excel chart using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773544/adding-a-text-box-to-an-excel-chart-using-openpyxl), but this seems to be related drawing textboxes in a chart. I would like to draw them related to cells, see below.

[image]