# Insert Texbox on excel using python

Tags: python, excel, textbox, openpyxl

I need to **insert a text box in an Excel sheet using python**, I have tried openpyxl, openpyxl.drawing.shape more specifically, xlsxwriter and on and it just doesn't work.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties
from openpyxl.drawing.shape import Shape

# Create a shape
shape = Shape()

# Initialize GraphicalProperties
graphical_properties = GraphicalProperties()

# Assign GraphicalProperties to spPr
shape.spPr = graphical_properties

# Add the shape to the worksheet
sheet.add_shape(shape)

# Save the workbook
workbook.save("output.xlsx")
```

This is the latest code that I tried.

Comment: You can try xlsxwriter, like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773544/adding-a-text-box-to-an-excel-chart-using-openpyxl

Comment: I tried that one but its giving me this error: xlwrsheet.insert_textbox(rrow,ccol,ttxt, xlwropts)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert_textbox'

Comment: Your problem with the suggested Xlsxwriter code is likely the example worksheet definition. There is no sheet to get by name on a new workbook. Most likely the error you got was because `xlwrsheet` was not an Xlsxwriter worksheet object. Change the line to `xlwrsheet = xlwrwb.add_worksheet()`. Note also with Xlsxwriter; this module creates new workbooks only it cannot open existing workbooks.

Comment: What if you just copy the example from this XlsxWriter doc: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_xlsxwriter/python_xlsxwriter_textbox.htm

Comment: I see what you are saying, I tried the link that you shared and it works, the only thing is that I need to place this series of textbox on an existing excel file with multiple sheets, If I get to to first the calculations then the textboxes and then insert tables and charts on the excel sheet there is a high possibility that all textboxes end up in the back of the charts.

Comment: Shapes are really, really complicated. The OOXML is common to all applications and extremely abstract. Openpyxl 3.2 will include read/write support for shapes but I wouldn't recommend it for client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openpyxl doesn't play well with shapes so better to use Xlsxwriter as mentioned or if you want to add to an existing workbook you can use Xlwings or win32com.

The code below is an example for Xlwings;

The AddShape command is from Excel and the shape type is from the [MsoAutoShapeType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.MsoAutoShapeTyperect), e.g. 1 is a rectangle and 9 is a circle.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int

excel_file = 'shapes.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    ### Excel AddShape command, Values are Type, Left, Top, Width & Height
    shape1 = ws.api.Shapes.AddShape(1, 100, 50, 150, 30)  # 1 is a rectangle
    shape2 = ws.api.Shapes.AddShape(9, 1, 1, 20, 20)  # 9 is a circle

    shape1_name = shape1.Name
    shape1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgb_to_int((255,233,0))

    shape2.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hello There"

    ### Some parameters are accessible from ws.shapes
    for shape in ws.shapes:
        if shape.name == shape1_name:
            shape.characters.api.Text = f"Shape Name = {shape.name}"
            shape.characters.font.name = 'Arial'
            shape.characters.font.color = (0,0,0)
            shape.characters.font.bold = True

            ### You can also add a macro to the object
            # shape.api.OnAction = "sample_sub"

    wb.save(excel_file)
```

[image]

Comment: It works it opens the file it creates the textbox at the end: wb.save(file) it shows this error and stops the loop: self.impl.save(path, password=password)
self.xl.SaveAs( v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
in SaveAs return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Cannot access 'Brand_Health_Tracker - 2 03-26-2024.xlsx'.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: I am trying to think of a situation where such an error would occur. You do mention a loop, are you saving the workbook each time while looping and writing to the XLSX file? If so you should only ever save the file once, at the end after all data is written to and before exiting the code. Or is the file 'Brand_Health_Tracker - 2 03-26-2024.xlsx'. located on a drive that you may lose access to? Otherwise I'd probably need to see what your code is (around the save section).

Comment: Regardless of the existence or otherwise of the file, `wb.save('Brand_Health_Tracker - 2 03-26-2024.xlsx')` should overwrite the existing file or create and write the file.